# how to intercept Button click inside UIWebview on IOS?

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, uiwebview, onclick

I have a HTML form that has certain fields which i am opening inside a UIWebview. On click of a particular button i want to do a in app action.

The approach i'm using now is on click of the button i redirect the page to a dummy URL. I sniff the URL using delegate method "shouldStartLoadWithRequest" and stop the redirection. I then do my custom event (capture image and upload) and then continue. This seems to be an ugly hack. Anyway i can directly hook into the button click event rather than a page redirection?

**UPDATE**
There seems to be no way to setup a delegate method to fire when a JS function is called on button click. The only way to do this is to use the URL sniffing method mentioned above. This has been explained in detail by joern below, so I will accept his answer.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can do the following:

In your HTML

```
<a class="yourButton" href="inapp://capture">Button Text</a>
```

In your UIWebViewDelegate

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
   if ([request.URL.scheme isEqualToString:@"inapp"]) {
      if ([request.URL.host isEqualToString:@"capture"]) {
         // do capture action
      }  
      return NO;
   }  
   return YES;
}
```

I added "capture" to your button's URL so that you could distinguish between several buttons that should trigger different actions (if you want to):

Comment: Yes, this is the approach i'm already using. Is there anyway to add an action to the Button via code? This may not be possible due to sandboxing i suppose, but just wanted to make sure.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean with "action"?

Comment: I meant how to add a function(method) to the button click so that the callback of the button click goes to this function. Is it possible? or is URL interception the only way to do this?

Comment: You can only do this if you are calling a javascript function inside your HTML (or external JS file). If you do want to call an Objective-C method the right way would be the way I describe in my answer. If you need the result of the method back in the HTML you'd have to return it via the stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: method

Comment: Yes i am calling a JS function from the HTML. I wanted to know if we could have a delegate method to fire when that function is called that would not require to sniff the URL. But guess that is not possible.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. The only way how the HTML can communicate with the Objective-C is via the UIWebViewDelegate method mentioned above. That is what it's there for. So you should not feel guilty to use it ;-)

Comment: say @joern do you know - - in my UIWebView, I have an ordinary form.  the form has a ordinary html "submit" button.  I want the html-submit button to, in fact, actually submit the form, AND, I want to catch the click in the iOS app.  is it possible?  thanks for this answer!

Comment: sorry @joern, i didn't realise it was "you" who just answered my other two critical css questions !!!  i wouldn't have asked yet another question of you   :)

Comment: @JoeBlow No problem ;-) You could intercept the click on the Submit button as described above and then replace the `// do capture action` comment with a call to a javascript function in your HTML that submits the form.

Comment: thanks!  to be clear then, there's no way to allow the ordinary-html-submit button to DO BOTH the ordinary submission of html, AND, call back to ios?  TBC it's an absolutely simple form, and I don't need the result that comes back (and barely matters if it does not connect)

Comment: Oh yes, wait. In the above example just return `YES` instead of `NO` after you captured the action. Then the form will be submitted normally as if nothing happened. No need to call a javascript function.

Comment: Dear @joern, got it, completely understood.  Incredibly, I actually tried it myself, and figured it out  :)  thanks.  I find `if (navigationType == .FormSubmitted)` and similar works well .......  THANKS AGAIN, REALLY

Comment: Will this work if the button needs a few ms to be rendered by a client side framework such as React/Vue. Will IOS wait/retry until it finds it?

Comment: @joern Will this work if the button needs a few ms to be rendered by a client side framework such as React/Vue. Will IOS wait/retry until it finds it?

Answer (score 3):

This code:

```
<a class="yourButton" href="inapp://capture">Restart</a>
```

doesn't work for me.

I've added **"inapp://capture"** in my javascript code for event function

```
KeyboardInputManager.prototype.restart = function (event) {
  window.location.href = "inapp://capture";
  //other code
};
```

Also I use the UIWebViewDelegate and It works for iOS 8, 9.

Answer (score 1):

For swift 4.2

Button code in HTML side:

```
<a class="catch-iOS" href="inapp://home">Продолжить покупки</a>
```

UIWebViewDelegate method:

```
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebView.NavigationType) -> Bool {
    if request.url?.scheme == "inapp" {
        if request.url?.host == "home" {
            // do something
        }
    }
    return true
}
```