# IOS - Open videos in Media Player when using UIWebView

Tags: ios, html, media-player

I want to launch Media Player upon clicking on a video link within UIWebView. The content of the UIWebView is an HTML5 page on my server, so whether the solution is to change the code in XCode or HTML5 I will be able to handle it.

All the videos in question are of 'mp4' extension - Just in case this addition helps.

**Please note this is for an iPad-only App.**

Comment: What have you tried?  Could you post code?  It seems unclear if this is a webpage from within an app, or using Safari?  Are the videos loaded from a remote location or do they live on the app?

Comment: No they do not live inside the App. They exist on my web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code could be modified to launch a video based on a button click from within the app.

```
    NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"filename" ofType:@"mp4"];
    //LOCAL FILE    
    NSURL    *fileURL    =   [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];
    //REMOTE FILE
    NSURL    *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://someurlsomewhere.com/movie.mp4"];
    player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
    player.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);
    [self.view addSubview:player.view];
    player.fullscreen = NO;
    [player play];
```

Here is a link that covers detecting taps/clicks from a webview which may be what you need in order to trigger the video.
[how to intercept Button click inside UIWebview on IOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992339/how-to-intercept-button-click-inside-uiwebview-on-ios)

Comment: This seems very much promising. I am sure combining the solution of the other Stack Overflow question with the code you listed about playing the video in Media will do the job. Let me try this process later on today and if it worked out, I will come back and mark your answer correct. Thank you!

Comment: Just a side question, will Media Player work in the iPad Simulator? Or I need a real device for this purpose? Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to run it in the media player on simulator.

Comment: Your code needed a bit of tweaking, but overall it works so great. Following the other post and yours helped a lot to achieve the desired result. Thank You!