# Hyperlink in the UITextField text

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield

I have an Social networking app where users can create challenges and add some special keyword start with # we called this as Tags for challenge, a single challenge can have multiple tags. All challenges will be displayed on the timeline with it's full information. Now I want to add UIButton or something else where #Tags occur in the UITextfield. so if user tap on any #Tag I will be able to able to show all Challenges using same #Tag.

In simple word I want to get the #Tag where user tap.!

[This is how a challenge description will look like in timeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFHpx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check out this [library](https://github.com/lukeredpath/LRLinkableLabel). You can use it to create labels with clickable hyperlinks (you can use the same approach with detecting hash tags areas and putting UIButton instances over them in `drawRect` method).
2. Another options is to use UIWebView with static HTML instead of UITextField to store text with hash tags. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992339/how-to-intercept-button-click-inside-uiwebview-on-ios) for reference.

Comment: Library link says page not found.