# Bind html button click with objective c

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I am developing iPad application in which i am loading `.html` pages in my webView.

One of the page `sample.html` page contain 2 buttons on click of that buttons i want to write some code in `Objective c`

In short i want to bind click event of buttons located in `.html` in `Objective c

Is it possible to write code for the same?

Comment: can you please show me html code for your button?

Comment: can you pl. check the below stack overflow link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992339/how-to-intercept-button-click-inside-uiwebview-on-ios

Comment: Checkout this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10995920/468724

Comment: @shri your answer is correct but it is compulsory to add my button inside `<a>` tag ?

Comment: If the button is on a html page then we can normally use a name attribute on a anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

Check with url request attribute to identify button click -

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{

    NSLog(@"url: %@", [[request URL] absoluteString]);

    return YES;

}
```