# How to get done button action in UIWebView default player?

Tags: swift, webview, uiwebview, ios9, swift2

I am working on iOS app. I need to play video in the UIWebView.Every things is working fine but my requirement is to get done button action.

Can we handle webView done button action or not in iOS.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992339/how-to-intercept-button-click-inside-uiwebview-on-ios Maybe it helps

Comment: My requirement is handle webView default Player done button, not in the WebView.